# PhoneGap or Apache Cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, web

Recently I was researching for a good cross-platform framework and found **PhoneGap** and **Apache Cordova**. I got a little confuse, and I want to fill some holes.

- I know that PhoneGap is a distribution of Apache Cordova, like Ubuntu is a distribution of linux. 
  So is that means that PhoneGap has more features? What kind of features? Does it make PhoneGap better? Does PhoneGap can do stuffs Cordova can't?
- Which one has the bigger community?
- Performance.. I know they will never provide the same experience like a native app, but I just want to know if PhoneGap/Cordova can run a simple client application with some UI animations smoothly? And Which one performs better?

The worst part is that Microsot supports developing Apache Cordova applications on Visual Studio and there's no support for developing Phone Gap. Just made my decision harder.

Answer (score 5):

I've been working on Cordova and PhoneGap projects for around 2 years now so I can try to help answer some of your questions as best as I can.

1. PhoneGap is maintained primarily by Adobe which allows Adobe to offer services such as PhoneGap Build and integration with Dreamweaver. There are minor things that Adobe provides (such as a [nice app](http://app.phonegap.com) that lets you preview your app on a device without installing the app), but the general rule of thumb is that every plugin can run on Cordova, and most of that can run on PhoneGap (because Cordova is the base of PhoneGap). Also, Cordova seems to get updates faster because of the [active community](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:changelog-panel) tracking issues and fixing them. An example being when the iPhone 6 and iOS 8 came out, Cordova was updated for those screen sizes within a week and PhoneGap took a bit longer.
2. Cordova generally has the larger community based on my experience. I can't give you direct numbers, but if you look at some GitHub plugins, the majority of people I see are using Cordova.
3. Honestly, they both perform the same. They are just UI Web Views and it mainly depends on the JS animation engine. I wouldn't use Jquery animate. I prefer to use Velocity.js, but like you said, it's tough to obtain native performance.

Basically, either way you'll have slightly less than par performance, but I just prefer Cordova because most plugins I have found are made for Cordova and I don't really use Adobe's services. I hope this helps and I would be glad to help if you have any other questions!

Liam

Comment: ALL the cordova plugins are compatible with phonegap because phonegap is built on top of cordova

Answer (score 1):

Phonegap and Cordova are the same thing. Phonegap is renamed Cordova in 2011.
You must use Cordova because it's newer and because there is a critical bug in pre 3.4 (or 3.5) version, this it's a problem if you want upload it on playstore.

Performance today is good, not like native app, but phones are now very fast so...